# Can I (and How do I) use my askubuntu account on other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stackexchange, user-accounts

I signed into (and presumably registered with) askubuntu using my launchpad openid.

I'd like to also ask some questions on other Stack Exchange sites but keep all the accounts connected.

When I go to sign in at (for example) stack overflow, the openid options do not include askubuntu or launchpad. How can I ensure that any new accounts I create will be correctly linked?
Should I register an account with the main stack exchange site first?
I seem to already be a Stack Exchange user as I can click on "Network Profile", and this takes me to Stack Exchange where I can see my stats, but I don't seem to have an actual log in to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's quite simple. You simply create an account on another Stackexchage site with the same credentials(assuming your Launchpad ***username*** is *example*, click the option for something like "other", and type , https://launchpad.net/~*example* and continue the login. This has a benefit--if you hit 200 reputation on any one StackExchange site, you get an extra 100 reputation for all sites. Unfortunately, you can only get this bonus once.

Another option to login:
Go to your Askubuntu profile page and click "My Logins". Click "add more logins.." and use any option there to create a login with a site you already have an account on. You can then login to any site in order to share the account.